# Python increase the number of elements in a list with same distribution

Tags: python, list

I want to increase the number of elements in a list by following same distribution.

My code:

```
# Presently I have 5 elements
x_now = [4,4.5,4.6,5.4,6]
# I want to produce 13 elements. My expected output
x_exp = [4,4.5,4.6,5.4,6,4,4.5,4.6,5.4,6,4,4.5] % I got it by copy and pasting existing list elements
# Is it possible to randomly sample between min and max here and produce n elements here: 
x_exp1 =[4 4.2 4.6 4.9 5.5 5.9 4.3  4.7 4.8 5.6 6 4.1 4.6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1

```
(x * 2)+(x[:13%len(x)])
```

Option 2

```
[x[i%len(x)] for i in range(13)]
```

Comment: How to resample the list? I mean, I want to produce `n` elements by following same distribution. My expected output something be like `[4 4.2 4.6 4.9 5.5 5.9 4.3  4.7 4.8 5.6 6 4.1 4.6]`

Comment: `[random.choice(x) for i in range(13)]` this will resample the list

Comment: Yes! This is much I wanted. Great answer. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
In [1431]: l = x_now * 3                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [1432]: l[:len(l)-(13 // len(x_now))]                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[1432]: [4, 4.5, 4.6, 5.4, 6, 4, 4.5, 4.6, 5.4, 6, 4, 4.5, 4.6]
```

Comment: I thought the same, however he wants 13 values repeating linearly through the original list.

Comment: Close enough. With this I can obtain either 10 or 15. How about producing 13 elements

Comment: Got it. Updating in a bit.

Comment: I don't want to snipe you, but I would do something with list-comprehension: `[x[i%len(x)] for i in range(13)]`

Comment: @HampusLarsson A simple mathematical operation would also suffice I guess.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I disagree. What if you wanted the list to be 100-long instead? You would then have to extent the list even further. What if you wanted less than the original list? Then the extension isn't necessary.

Comment: @HampusLarsson That sounds right. Your solution would be better.